# Can't see new branches created on GIT

Tags: git, bitbucket, branch, pull

When somebody creates a new branch on our git repository I can't see the new branch. I've made *git pull* (through eclipse plugin and with git-bash) but it doesn't work (Already up to date)

I've tried also with *git fetch* or *git checkout* but it doesn't work either (error: pathspec 'XXXXX' did not match any file(s) known to git).

The only thing that works is remove the project and clone again...

Do you know why is this happening? Why I can't see new branches on my repository? Is something about permissions?

We have git version 2.25.0 and Bitbucket.

When I run *git config remote.origin.fetch* command, it doesn't appears anything
$ git config remote.origin.fetch

Thank you so much
Best regards

Comment: `git pull` won't help in general; you want `git fetch`. But: is your clone a *single-branch* clone? If so, you won't see any other branches in the other Git, because you told *your* Git: *Close your eyes and ears to all other branches.*

Comment: New branches do not get to exist in the local repository automatically after `git pull`. But remote tracking branches do if the repository is properly created and configured. You can try `git branch -a` after `git pull` or `git fetch` to see what branches and remote tracking branches exist.

Comment: if I use git branch -a I can't see the new branches after git pull or git fetch. I've used also git remote update + git fetch but it doesn't work either

Comment: @JLopez Try `git fetch origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` and run `git branch -a`. Besides, you can use `git ls-remote --heads` in the local repository to print the branches that exist in the remote repository.

Comment: How did you make your clone originally? Did you use `git clone <url>`, or did you add various options?

Comment: @JLopez : can you please type `git config remote.origin.fetch` in git bash and paste the output in your question ?

Comment: @torek From the Git doc for `git pull`: *Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch. In its default mode, `git pull` is shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge FETCH_HEAD`*. So `git pull`ing shouldn't be the issue here.

Comment: @potame: the problem is that, depending on how you and Git use it, `git pull` sometimes runs `git fetch` in such a way that no *other* remote-tracking name gets updated (and if your Git version predates 1.8.2, not even the one particular remote-tracking name gets updated either, though that's not an issue here). Running a bare `git fetch` updates all remote-tracking names.

Comment: git config remote.origin.fetch done, but it doesn't show info